# To use Interactions or to split the sample?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

I have panel data for 16 years and 134 countries. I am using fixed effects model and using following regression models:

Model 1: 
$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \epsilon   $

Model 2: 
$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_1*X_2 + \epsilon   $

All three variables are continuous. The main variable of interest is $ X_1$ but I expect the effect of $ X_1$ on $ y$ to be different for countries with different values of $ X_2$. To be specific, theory predicts that value of $ X_1$ will be higher for high values of $ X_2$ i.e. significant positive sign of interactions. I also expect positive signs for $ \beta_1$ and $ \beta_2$.

The problem is that $ X_2$ is insignificant in Model 1. I have different proxies for $ X_2$ but none of them is significant. More troublesome part is that when I include interactions (Model 2), $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ become significant with opposite signs. I played around a little, sometimes the sign flips for $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ but they always are opposite which is conceptually wrong.

Alternatively, I could split the sample into groups based on values of $X_2$. I divided the sample into three groups on the basis of their values of $X_2$ ($\mu \pm \sigma  $) and ran Model 1 without $X_2$. By doing this, I am able to explain my story very nicely i.e. for model with high values of $X_2$, the coefficient of $X_1$ is higher in magnitude but the obvious question (which was asked in the conference I presented this) was "why did you not include $X_2$ in the regression?". Now I cannot simply say that interactions were not working well for me, can I?

My questions are:
1) why do interactions become significant when the moderating variable is not significant in the main model and why does it always have opposite signs?

2) is it OK to divide the sample based on a moderating variable instead of using interactions? if yes, what would be the explanation if someone asks the big question "WHY?"

Comment: Some thoughts: (1) If you split your sample instead of including the interactions, you do not restrict the effect of interactions to be linear. (2) You could play with different splits to see how the effect varies. E.g. try a "rolling split": rank the cases by the relevant variable and model the cases ranked 1st to 20th; 2nd to 21st; ... 115th to 134th. Plot you results. (3) Is it honest to torture the data until it confesses (i.e. until it gives you the answer you want)? Maybe the data is telling you a different story than you initially anticipated and you are not willing to listen.

Comment: (4) From my limited experience in scientific conferences, I don't think anything is inherently wrong with reporting what you actually did and why some of your trials failed. You are not supposed to hit the bullseye on your first shot. Explaining carefully what you tried (including the failures) may encourage comments from the audience with hints and tips on how these things could be done better. (5) Splitting the sample instead of using interactions will be less efficient in a sense that you estimates of $\beta_1$ will each use only a part of all the available observations due to the split(s).

Comment: Thank you @RichardHardy for your insightful comments. I will try your rolling splits suggestion. About not willing to listen, according to the current results, the effect of human capital on economic growth is less for countries with high control for corruption and high level of government effectiveness. One might say that this result might be driven  by the fact the most countries with less corruption are developed. I controlled for level of development, still result persists. data might be a problem as level of governance is a subjective measure Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I am also beginning to realize that the main effect of $X_2$ has almost the same coefficient in magnitude as the interaction but with opposite sign when interaction is significant (-0.0831 and +0.0827 for example). I understand that marginal effect with interactions will also include $X_1$ in it so the effects will not cancel each other out but it seems to me that the interaction is messing up due to high multicollinearity with the main effect ($X_2$). I have tried to standardize it and mean-center it but it does not go away.